# Detecting largest polygons in an image?

Tags: python, image, opencv, polygon

I am trying to detect polygon with the largest area in the image but the image consist of some noise and small polygons.
Anyone has done any work regarding this?
  I am using open-cv right now.

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have already tried, together with some sample images and the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'm writing this as answer because I can't write comments due to reputation number.

You should attach some code you have tried and some screenshots of the problem.

I will link a solution in java and it's not that hard to convert to python

```
  Mat mGray = new Mat();

    MatOfDouble mu = new MatOfDouble();

    MatOfDouble stddev = new MatOfDouble();

    Imgproc.cvtColor(origMat, origMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2BGR);

    Imgproc.cvtColor(origMat, mGray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    Core.meanStdDev(mGray, mu, stddev);

    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(mGray, mGray, new Size(5, 5), 5);

    //Imgproc.Canny(mGray, mGray, 30, 80, 3, false);   //FOR HIGH BRIGHTNESS
    //Imgproc.Canny(mGray, mGray, 50, 130, 3, false);    // FOR LOW BRIGHTNESS

    Imgproc.Canny(mGray, mGray, mu.get(0, 0)[0], stddev.get(0, 0)[0], 3, false);

    Mat kernell = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(9, 9));

    Imgproc.morphologyEx(mGray, mGray, Imgproc.MORPH_CLOSE, kernell);

    Imgproc.dilate(mGray, mGray, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_CROSS, new Size(3, 3)));

    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();

    Mat hierarchy = new Mat();

    Imgproc.findContours(mGray, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    double largest_area = 0;

    Rect rect = new Rect();
    int largest_idx = 0;

    for (int idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++) {

        double a = Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(idx));  //Find the area of contour

        if (a > largest_area) {

            largest_area = a;

            // rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(idx));

            largest_idx = idx;
        }
    }

    MatOfPoint2f new_mat = new MatOfPoint2f(contours.get(largest_idx).toArray());

    RotatedRect rbox = Imgproc.minAreaRect(new_mat);

    Point vertices[] = new Point[4];

    rbox.points(vertices);

    List<MatOfPoint> boxContours = new ArrayList<>();

    boxContours.add(new MatOfPoint(vertices));

    //Imgproc.drawContours(origMat, boxContours, 0, new Scalar(255, 255, 0), 2);

    /* *******************************************************************************************
     * draw the detected rotated rect in the original image
     *******************************************************************************************/
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        Imgproc.line(origMat, vertices[i], vertices[(i + 1) % 4], new Scalar(255, 0, 0));
    }
```

Mainly, I'm converting the input image to gray scale, reduce noise with the Gaussian filter, Canny min and max threshold values are calculated using the image mean and standard deviation values, this will adjust threshold values accordingly with environment brightness.

Then apply findContours function and loop through found contours and draw the largest one.

I hope this solution helps you.